# (Oracle SQL, PLSQL) How to delete columns, which are entirely NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question regarding my Oracle SQL / PLSQL Table:
I have a Table with Values. Some of the Columns have no Values in all Rows at all. How do I therefore delete these columns, which are entirely NULL?

incase someones suggestion includes to transpose the tablem its too difficult for me to use Pivot, because the values are too different.

The Table has about 40 columns and 121 Rows.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: what i meant was, it would be great if the empty columns could be "automatically" be detected and deleted/removed/deselected.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Initially, I thought you want to DROP columns which are empty (you'd do that with ALTER TABLE) because UPDATE to NULL is useless as those values are NULL already But then you said you can't use PIVOT; what does it have to do with *deleting* values? Shortly, no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: what i meant was, it would be great if the empty columns could be "automatically" be detected and deleted/removed/deselected.

Comment: There is no automatic process: you'll need to write something yourself. Because this is **not something we would want to happen automatically**. Any change to the physical data model needs to be done deliberately, in a controlled fashion and with due regard for the impact on existing applications e.g. finding and modifying code which references those redundant columns.

Comment: i meant that is there a way to code this, where it will figure out the empty columns and delete these columns?

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the columns using aggregation.  Here is one method that puts the names in a single column:

```
select ((case when count(col1) = 0 then 'col1,' end) ||
        (case when count(col2) = 0 then 'col2,' end) ||
        . . .
       ) as cols
from t;
```

Then you can use `alter table` to actually drop the columns.

Comment: thank you !! whats the use of 'col1' and 'col2' ? do i combine these with alter table? if so, how?

Comment: Now you are back to 'alter table.  It is still not clear what you want to do.  Do you want to (A) actually remove the column from the table structure, as suggested by your opening statement and reference to ALTER TABLE or (B) just bypass the column in some reporting, as suggested by your reference to PIVOT?

Comment: (A) actually remove the column from the table structure, as suggested by my opening statement and reference to ALTER TABLE

Comment: @ShahbazShahSyed . . . Those are thenames of the columns, which you can use in the `alter table` statement.